# What do 'fain' and 'unfained' mean in this paragraph from Milton's "The Doctrine & Discipline of Divorce"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, early-modern-english

In [book one](https://milton.host.dartmouth.edu/reading_room/ddd/book_1/text.shtml), chapter VI, of *The Doctrine & Discipline of Divorce*, it is written:

> Fourthly, Mariage is a cov’nant the very beeing wherof consists, not in a forc’t cohabitation, and counterfet performance of duties, but in **unfained** love and peace. And of matrimoniall love no doubt but that was chiefly meant, which by the ancient Sages was thus parabl’d, That Love, if he be not twin-born, yet hath a brother wondrous like him, call’d Anteros: whom while he seeks all about, his chance is to meet with many fals and **faining** Desires that wander singly up and down in his likenes.

I tried to decode the meaning of *[fain](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fain#English)* and *unfained* in Milton's writing but to no avail. Are these just alternative spellings of *[fine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fine#Verb)* (meaning to diminish) and *unfined*?

Comment: I would suggest that _unfained_ is Milton's spelling of _unfeigned_. I'm not sure about _faining_.

Comment: Assuming "fals" is "false", "faining" is almost certainly "feigning".

Comment: To feign is to pretend. Authentic love and peace gets Milton's vote. False and inauthentic desires can take a hike, that is, wander singly.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate (adjectival) meaning is summarised and exemplified in M-W as

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fain1)
> a: WILLING
> *he was very fain, for the young widow was "altogether fair and lovely …*
> b: being obliged or constrained : COMPELLED
> *Great Britain was fain to devote its whole energy … to the business of slaying and being slain*

This is consistent with an *Oxford Languages* definition (which I cannot  reference because of pay-wall) quoted by Google search for *fain* as:

1. pleased or willing under the circumstances.
   "*the traveller was fain to proceed*"
2. compelled by the circumstances; obliged.
   "*he was fain to acknowledge that the agreement was sacrosanct*"

Hence, we may understand
*but in unfained love and peace*
as
*in unconstrained (unforced, willingly accepted etc) love and peace*

and understand
*to meet with many fals and faining Desires*
as
*to meet with many fals (false) and faining (restricting, compelling, forcing, unwillingly demanding etc) desires*

Fain and feign are sometimes confused:

> [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/fain-feign/)
> Fain is (1) an adjective meaning glad or content to do something, and (2) an adverb meaning willingly or gladly. It’s mostly archaic. It still appears occasionally, but in most modern examples we can find, the word is used to affect an archaic tone. Feign is a verb meaning to pretend, to give a false appearance of, or to imitate.

Comment: Like Kate Bunting, I read these as _unfeigned_ and _feigning_: the meaning fits perfectly, and seems more straightforward than your explanation. Note that the OED does give _fain(e)_ as an alternative spelling for _feign_, up to 1600.